# Microsoft.Bot.Connector - The To Address refers to {} which is not a known

Tags: c#, email, botframework

I'm developing a bot to be used with the email channel (Office 365).

I'm struggling to implement a "Starting a new conversation with the user", i.e. the bot should initiate conversation with the user(s) after receiving certain triggers.

I'm referencing the example available on [http://docs.botframework.com/](http://docs.botframework.com/connector/new-conversations/).

```
    var connector = new ConnectorClient();

    Message newMessage = new Message();
    newMessage.From = new ChannelAccount() {  Address = "[email the bot is registered with]", Name = "Awesome Bot", ChannelId = "email", IsBot = true };
    newMessage.To = new ChannelAccount() {  Address = user.Email, Name = $"{ user.FirstName } {user.LastName}", ChannelId = "email", IsBot = false };
    newMessage.Text = message;
    newMessage.Language = "en";

    connector.Messages.SendMessage(newMessage);
```

The bot is live in Azure and registered with the framework.
When I invoke the above code, looks like the connector is sending a request to api.botframework.com, but receives a status code 404 back. I'm also seeing the following error message:

> The To Address refers to [user email] which is not a known

It sounds like the error is cut off. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

We were worried about spammers abusing the ability to send email through our servers, so we limited the ability to send a message to people who are not already in the conversation or users of the system.  Our thoughts are that we will enable this functionality as part of being approved in our directory or as for paid clients.

Comment: Unfortunately, it would be very hard to commit to publishing anything in the directory when it cannot be completely tested. Wouldn't it better to set a reasonable limit on how many participants can be reached? Is this limitation only applicable to the email channel? I need to find a way for the bot to reach out to subscribed participants on a set schedule, and I'm assuming I cannot just store the conversationId and reuse every time bot wants to reach out to the subscriber. Any idea how I can implement (and test) starting conversations via email channel? Thank you for in advance!

Comment: @OlegB did you eventually figure it out?

Comment: This is way after the fact so it's probably not useful to @OlegB anymore, but I wouldn't be so sure that you can't just save and reuse the conversation. I'm using the Facebook channel rather than Email, but at least in my case, that's more or less how proactive messages are handled - by reusing saved info from an older conversation.