# Connecting a MS bot framework user to someone on Skype

Tags: c#, skype, botframework, chatbot

I've made a chat bot using Microsoft Bot Framework which answers a user's questions. When the bot is unable to answer the user's questions, I want to be able to redirect the user question to a customer rep on Skype.

The person on Skype will see the messages posted by the user, and his answers will be sent to the user.

I need some advice on how to achieve this connection (from user<->chatbot<->SkypecustomerRep)

Edit: 
I'm toying with the idea of using the commands in http://docs.botframework.com/connector/new-conversations/#navtitle

I figured when the LuisIntent would turn out to be None, I'd message a skype id with: 

    `var connector = new ConnectorClient();
    var message = new Message
    {
    From = new ChannelAccount(channelId: ""),
    To = new ChannelAccount() {ChannelId = "Skype", Address = "xyz@abc.com"},
    Text = result.Query,
    Language = "en"
    };`

where the email is the Skype id. I'm not able to figure out what should be in the From field (what's the channelId, Address of my bot)

EDIT:

I'm able to pass one message to Skype now, but when the Skype user replies, I observe that the reply is not immediately presented to the bot framework user. In other words, when the user types something into the chat window, he gets a response from the bot (as expected) and the skype user's delayed message.

Comment: Start by posting what you have tried so far.

Comment: Good point. I've posted it. Thanks

Comment: Did you success with sending one message to Skype ?

Comment: No, I get "The To Address refers to abc@fed.com which is not a known"
I'm not sure how to add a Skype id to 'Known', will probably post a separate question, since the one linked below hasn't been solved - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36585671/microsoft-bot-connector-the-to-address-refers-to-which-is-not-a-known

Answer (score 0):

If you want the customer support representative to have sufficient context (i.e. see more than just the most recent text posted by the user) you are going to need to build your own customer support interface to both record conversations as well as highlight those that need attention from a human.  Usually folks do this building their own client with DirectLine or connecting up their existing customer support client (also with DirectLine).  The bot then directly passes the support reps replies back to the end users.

Some additional detail can be seen in [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200249/3-different-channels-in-the-same-conversation-botframework/40728962#40728962).