# 3 different channels in the same conversation botframework

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I'm trying to do a C# MVC WebApplication for human-hybrid bots support customers, so I can't create a conversation between 3 different channels.

Example:

1-) An user start a chat with my bot in facebook

2-) When the bot receive the activity, he adds a new guy in conversation (directline, that's I have conversationId).

3-) The facebook user now, is chatting with other 2 users (bot and directline User).

Is the correct logic ?

I'm trying to create this group conversation but I'm getting error 500.

Comment: Need some more details to understand your scenario.  Is the bot posting to Facebook on behalf of the added user?  (i.e. you are trying to support group chat using a Facebook bot)

Comment: In fact, I would like to do a real-time mirroring of the bot's chat with the user on a chat monitor, and intervene in this conversation when I find it necessary. Maybe I did not pass the correct logic.

Comment: I see another frameworks doing it easily, but they don't give a total control of the bot. 
Bot framework appears is the best solution for bots, but I only saw basic samples, without real scenarios like this on the web.
I'm a little dumb to learn things quickly, and the way I learn most easily is through examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common scenario that I've seen addressed by a number of users in the following manner:

1. Build your customer support interface (CSI) (i.e. the side used by your customer support reps) using Direct Line
2. Your bot pipes through the all the user messages to the CSI which stores all the conversations.  Reps can see a list of all the users interacting with the bot and the history of each of those conversations.
3. When escalation to a human is needed, the bot flags one of the conversations needing attention
4. Your bot then brokers conversations between the accounts (i.e. Facebook End User <-> Your Bot <-> CSI).  Essentially the customer support rep is creating a response, which is being posted by the bot back to the end user

This means there's no need to add an additional person to the conversation.  (Facebook currently only allow 1-on-1 conversations with bots).