# Has anyone tried to do a handoff to human while using node.js botbuilder and LUIS?

Tags: node.js, azure-language-understanding, botframework

Has anyone tried to do a handoff to human while using node.js botbuilder and LUIS? Is there any example code anywhere?

Comment: See previous answer here: [3-different-channels-in-the-same-conversation-botframework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200249/3-different-channels-in-the-same-conversation-botframework/40728962#40728962)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [3 different channels in the same conversation botframework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200249/3-different-channels-in-the-same-conversation-botframework)

Comment: Thanks friends for your valuable suggestions. The below npm had solved the problem at that time: https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder-handoff. Although, Initially, i had written my own handoff code doing almost the same thing as the above npm. Now it seems that the npm is not ported to version 4.x of botbuilder