# FB chat bot Permission to make hybrid bot so human can reply from web panel

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots, botframework

I have developed FB messenger bot using Microsoft bot framework. The bot is ready and approved by FB.

Now I am working on the hybrid part so human(web panel user) can take over chat and do conversation.

Now Issue is, I don't now which permissions need to read and show bot conversation in my web panel.

Also, it will be great if you can suggest that should I need to save conversation in DB to show in web panel or Is it possible that I can make a direct get request to FB API and show.

Thanks.

Comment: Instead of down vote, let me know what is wrong here. I am here only to solve my query.

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40200249/3-different-channels-in-the-same-conversation-botframework

Comment: @SergeyL Thanks for the link, Bu here I would like to more about permission, that answer only contains the logical information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For FB Permission: pages_messaging

Development: 
Show message: From our database.
Reply message: Using [botframework](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/core-concepts/messages/#navtitle)